# C# how to make a live bar chart (Livecharts library)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2010, livecharts

I am transferring the numerical data to the graph in a Cartesian graph. However, I have a problem when extracting the data names from the database. Names do not appear. I want my data to appear like a pie chart next to the Cartesian graph. I want to match the data in the "GelirAdi" column to the chart. In summary "GelirAdi" column will be name, "GelirMiktari" will be numeric value in cartesien graph but how can I do that?

[image]

```
private void btn_gider_bilgi_getir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string veritabaniyolu = "Data source=veritabani.db";
    bunifuDataGridView1.DataSource = null;

    SQLiteConnection baglanti = new SQLiteConnection(veritabaniyolu);
    baglanti.Open();
    string sql_tarih_sorgula = "SELECT * FROM Gelirler";
    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql_tarih_sorgula, baglanti);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    bunifuDataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    baglanti.Close();

    ColumnSeries series2 = new ColumnSeries()
    {
        DataLabels = true,
        Values = new ChartValues<int>(),
        LabelPoint = point => point.Y.ToString()
    };
    Axis axisX = new Axis() {
        Separator = new Separator() { Step = 1, IsEnabled = false },
        Labels=new List<string>()
    };

    Axis axisY = new Axis()
    {
        LabelFormatter=y=>y.ToString(),
        Separator=new Separator()

    };
    cartesianChart1.Series.Add(series2);
    cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(axisX);
    cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(axisY);
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in bunifuDataGridView1.Rows) {

        int a = Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["GelirMiktari"].Value);
        series2.Values.Add(a);
        axisX.Labels.Add(item.Cells["GelirAdi"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your tags a quite useless. What chart library do you use?

Comment: I use the live charts lib

Comment: @BrktrL, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT 
really thank you so much. you help me a lot.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Can I ask one last thing? It says "Series" at the beginning of the graphic names. Examples= "Series Name","Series Blabla" etc.Why is there "Series" text.
How can I remove this "Series" text in the cartesien chart?

Comment: @BrktrL, you only set Title = "" in the ColumnSeries. Also, I updated in my code.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I can't thank you enough. I really thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my test, you can set the labelpoint's tooltip dynamically by using linq.

You can try the following code to achieve it.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite");
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from Product", m_dbConnection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColumnSeries series2 = new ColumnSeries()
        {
            DataLabels = true,
            Values = new ChartValues<int>(),
            LabelPoint = point => dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(i => Convert.ToDouble(i.Cells["number"].Value) == point.Y).Select(i => i.Cells["name"].Value.ToString()).First(),
            Title = ""               //Here you added to remove  "Series" text
            
        };
        Axis axisX = new Axis()
        {
            Separator = new Separator() { Step = 1, IsEnabled = false },
            Labels = new List<string>()
            
        };

        Axis axisY = new Axis()
        {
            LabelFormatter = y => y.ToString(),
            Separator = new Separator()

        };
        cartesianChart1.Series.Add(series2);
        cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(axisX);
        cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(axisY);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            int a = Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["number"].Value);
            series2.Values.Add(a);
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]